# App thinning issue on Xcode 9.2

Tags: bitcode, xcode9.2, app-thinning

Am trying to do app thinning in Xcode 9.2 where I have third party frameworks where some are installed through pods while others manually , am trying to test this so had an ad-hoc distribution profile , now I try exporting through this profile , have selected app thinning attaching screen shot  [bitcode option selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDVsO.png)

Then I sign choosing sign automatically from Xcode then the compiling bitcode comes [bitcode compiling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3G6b.png)

I get this error after say about 5 mins of compiling i.e. [bitcode error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzPKN.png)

Analysed through bit of logs with show log options particularly which IDEDistribution.log :

> PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/elektra.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib"
>   did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item

so there where such errors in this file related to all of the Swift dynamic libraries frameworks besides two of the private third party frameworks which is an embedded binary in the project. We are currently using both Objective C and Swift (mix match). Not able to figure out what could be the error , any help is much appreciated as am new to this.

Comment: Besides I have a run script which strips out i386 and x86_64 architectures.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it since one of the build setting was not proper reference : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1964/_index.html